# Merge Rows & Sum Values (+ removed merged ones)

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked and test for this since 48 hours and couldn't find the right solution (or correctly adapt an existing one).

Attached is a screenshot of my Excel. Basically, I want to say (in a function or VBA script): WHEN "ICCID" (column B) is the same THEN merge lines by concatenate "Country" (column M) AND sum-up values in columns O, P, and Q.
(and of course remove the lines which were merged)

Does anyone have a fix for this?
Thank you very much in advance[image]

Comment: Can you show us something you tried, even if it does not work. I would recommend using of a `Dictionary`, where to load unique ICCID as key and the like item an array containing the necessary cumulated/concatenated values. Do you want concatenating the countries without any separator between each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It places in a dictionary ICCIDs as (unique) keys, and an item array keeping the row to be updated, the concatenated country names and the cumulated necessary values. Using arrays and a dictionary, deleting the duplicate rows at once, it should be fast enough:

```
Sub mergeICCID()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrInt, i As Long, j As Long, iRow As Long, rngDel As Range, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in B:B
  
  arr = sh.Range("B2:Q" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration and processing
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
  
  'fill the dictionary:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(i, arr(i, 12), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 15), arr(i, 16))
        Else
            arrInt = dict(arr(i, 1))   'extract the item array
            arrInt(1) = arrInt(1) & ", " & arr(i, 12): arrInt(2) = arrInt(2) + arr(i, 14) 'concatenate country names and cumullate Usage Days
            arrInt(3) = arrInt(3) + arr(i, 15):  arrInt(4) = arrInt(4) + arr(i, 16)       'cummulate Usage value and Usage in Gb value
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrInt  'put back the adapted item array
            addToRange rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i + 1)  'set the UNION range keeping rows to be deleted (at once) at the end
        End If
  Next i
  
  'Change the cumulated/concatenated array elements:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        iRow = dict.Items()(i)(0)
        arr(iRow, 12) = dict.Items()(i)(1) 'concatenated country names
        arr(iRow, 14) = dict.Items()(i)(2) 'cumulated Usage Days value
        arr(iRow, 15) = dict.Items()(i)(3) 'cumulated Usage value
        arr(iRow, 16) = dict.Items()(i)(4) 'cumulated Usage in Gb value
  Next i
  
  'drop back the updated array content:
  sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr

  'delete the duplicate rows, at once:
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Private Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**:

Please, try the next version, which does  not update the range from A:A to L:L and process only cases having "EU" in N:N column:

```
Sub mergeICCID2Arrays()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrB, arr, arrInt, i As Long, j As Long, iRow As Long, rngDel As Range, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in B:B
  
  arrB = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Value   'place the B:B range in an array (to be used only for setting the dictionary keys)
  arr = sh.Range("M2:P" & lastR).Value2   'place the range in an array for faster iteration and processing
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
  
  'fill the dictionary:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 2) = "EU" Then 'process only cases having "EU" in column N:N
            If Not dict.Exists(arrB(i, 1)) Then
                dict.Add arrB(i, 1), Array(i, arr(i, 1), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4))
            Else
                arrInt = dict(arrB(i, 1))   'extract the item array
                arrInt(1) = arrInt(1) & ", " & arr(i, 1)                                           'concatenate country names
                arrInt(2) = arrInt(2) + arr(i, 3):  arrInt(3) = arrInt(3) + arr(i, 4)  'cummulate Usage Days and Usage values
                dict(arrB(i, 1)) = arrInt  'put back the adapted item aray
                addToRange rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i + 1)  'set the range keeping rows to be deleted
            End If
        End If
  Next i
  
  'Change the cumulated/concatenated array elements:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        iRow = dict.Items()(i)(0)
        arr(iRow, 1) = dict.Items()(i)(1) 'concatenated country names
        arr(iRow, 3) = dict.Items()(i)(2) 'cummulated Usage Days value
        arr(iRow, 4) = dict.Items()(i)(3) 'cummulated Usage value
 Next i
 
  'drop the adapted array content, at once:
  sh.Range("M2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
  
   'delete the duplicate rows, at once:
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works amazingly! I just have 4 questions remaining about that:

Comment: 1) How can I run this script only (IF) on rows where "Country Code" (Column N) is "EU"? So that it only merges rows with country code EU and not other.

Comment: 2) Is the MessageBox "Ready..." mandatory? I'd like to remove it, no interaction after the marco has run

Comment: 3) What is the PrivateSub addToRange... about? If I make no mistake that's an other macro, a second one, though it doesn't appear in the list of my macros. Thus, I'm not able to run it... What is it doing? Why is it there if I can't run it? Is it mandatory?

Comment: 4) Syntax error, the ICCID numbers do not appear correctly anymore, since the =" preceding them has been removed during the macro, Excel formats them strangely. Is it possible to frame these numbers with ="" please? So that they are displayed correctly.

Comment: @Benjamin Perry 1. Such a condition should be placed when the dictionary is loaded. 2. No, it is not. It was only a notification to observe how fast is the code. You can delete the line 3.  It is necessary, is the one creating the `Union` range, based on it the duplicate rows deletion can be done. 4. You did not say anything about formulas in the range to be processed. The code can be adapted to build a new array which to skip the first column, but are there other such cases in the range to be processed? And not so clear the ICCID issue: Doesn't it show correctly, except not being a formula?

Comment: @Benjamin Perry Is the ICCID shown in scientific format? If it will be dropped down **as text** will it be OK?

Comment: 1) How-to? I don't know how to write it... 3) So how is it called? As I cannot run it from the macro dashboard, it doesn't show up... 4) No other such case, that's the only one. Just the number in the ICCID column that are not formatted properly by Excel when not within ="". We just have to put the numbers (let's say: 123456) like this: ="123456" so that Excel's correctly displays them. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to manually format it as text but even then Excel doesn't display correctly. It needs to be within =""

Comment: @Benjamin Perry `AddToRange` is a (necessary) `Sub` having two parameters and it is called from the main macro: `addToRange rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i + 1)`. So, your single problem about the ICCID is the fact that Excel interprets it as a number and use scientific format. Is this understanding a correct one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248015/discussion-between-benjamin-perry-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Benjamin Perry Please, test the new code (after **Edited**) and send some feedback.

Comment: New code you sent works perfectly! Only thing is that it doesn't remove the rows after merging them (previous code did that but not this one)

Comment: Please, replace Select with Delete in the last code line. I tested it in this way...

Comment: I am driving now...